# Dockerize my gradle java project but encounter jdk version mismatch between compile time and runtime

Tags: java, docker, gradle, dockerfile, build.gradle

I am developing a gradle java project (it is pure java not spring-boot).

I dockerize the project with multi-stage Dockerfile in order to slim the final image size:

```
FROM gradle:7.4.2-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY . .
RUN gradle :myapp:build

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine as my-app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /home/app/MyApp/build/libs/MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

As you see above, I am using base image `openjdk:8-jre-alpine` for running the application jar.  I choose it as base image because it is very slim.

I build the project by `docker build -t myapp .` & it is successful.

I run it by `docker run myapp`, however I get error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/MyApp has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
```

My interpretation of the error is my Java class is built with a higher JDK version while at runtime the the base image I choose `openjdk:8-jre-alpine` is using an older version JRE to run. (Please correct me if I am wrong here.)

I would like to keep using that base image because it is small in size. So I decided to compile my code using java 11 jdk.

I tried specifying the older java version for building project by adding the following in my `build.gradle` :

```
java {
  toolchain {
    languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(11))
  }
}
```

and then, build the image again `docker build -t myapp .`, but now I get building error:

```
#12 45.30 Could not determine the dependencies of task ':myapp:compileJava'.
#12 45.30 > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':common:compileClasspath'.
#12 45.30    > Failed to calculate the value of task ':myapp:compileJava' property 'javaCompiler'.
#12 45.31       > Provisioned toolchain '/home/gradle/.gradle/jdks/adoptium-11-x64-hotspot-linux' could not be probed.
```

I guess that is because the base image I use doesn't have that jdk?? (Please correct me if I understood wrongly here)

So, I wonder what is the proper way to have my project being built by java 11 jdk & I could still use that base image?

**===== More try I did =====**

I forgot to mention that I also guessed the image `openjdk:8-jre-alpine` might hint it only support java-8, so I renamed it to `openjdk:11-jre-alpine` for java-11, when build the image I encounter the following error, I guess it means the image doesn't exist?

```
[+] Building 1.5s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                        
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 386B                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:11-jre-alpine                                                                                                                                     1.4s
 => CANCELED [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/gradle:7.4.2-alpine                                                                                                                                    1.4s
 => [auth] library/gradle:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [auth] library/openjdk:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:11-jre-alpine:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: docker.io/library/openjdk:11-jre-alpine: not found
```

Comment: Your conclusion is correct: Java code compiled with a newer version of the compiler usually does not work on an older version of the Java runtime. The solution is simple: make sure you are using the same version when compiling and running your code. I would advise you to use something newer than Java 8 in your Docker container; Java 8 is an old version that is not supported anymore.

Comment: @Jesper, thanks, I already tried what your comment suggested as you see in my post that I specified java 11 for compiling but encounter error.  If you have a concrete suggestion about which base image is better to use than the one I am using now & size is small, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, just to clarify: from what I see `openjdk:8-jre-alpine` is supporting java 11, not limited by java 8. That's why I specify java 11 in `build.gradle`.  I could of course change to another base image which is another direction for solving the problem, the concern is the size of image & which image should I use, I hope someone could give suggestion there too.

Comment: `openjdk:8-jre-alpine` is Java 8, not Java 11. That's why there's an "8" in the name. A smaller image that supports Java 11 is `openjdk:11-jre-slim` (about 76 MB). Note that this image contains a JRE, not a JDK so there is no Java compiler in there (you cannot use this if you need to compile inside the container). See https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk?tab=tags&page=1&name=11-jre

Comment: I guessed so, and tried replacing 8 to 11 in the image name yesterday, it was not working. Let me try again now....   OK, tried again, the error is `failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: docker.io/library/openjdk:11-jre-alpine: not found
`, there is no such image if I understand the error correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html)

> **Java SE   |    Released   |   Major  |  Supported majors**
>
> 1.0.2  |  May 1996  | 45   | 45
>
> 1.1 |     February 1997    | 45   |  45
>
> 1.2 | December 1998    | 46   | 45 .. 46
>
> 1.3    | May 2000  | 47   | 45 .. 47
>
> 1.4   | February 2002 |   48 |    45 .. 48
>
> 5.0   | September 2004 |  49 |    45 .. 49
>
> 6 |   December 2006 | 50 |    45 .. 50
>
> 7 |   July 2011 | 51 |    45 .. 51
>
> **8**  | March 2014   | 52    | **45 .. 52**
>
> 9 |   September 2017 |    53 |    45 .. 53
>
> 10 | March 2018 | 54 |    45 .. 54
>
> 11 | September 2018 | 55 |    45 .. 55
>
> 12 | March 2019 | 56 |    45 .. 56
>
> 13 | September 2019 | 57 |    45 .. 57
>
> 14 | March 2020 | 58 |    45 .. 58
>
> 15 | September 2020 | 59 |    45 .. 59
>
> 16 | March 2021 | 60 |    45 .. 60
>
> **17** | September 2021 | **61** |    **45 .. 61**
>
> 18 | March 2022 | 62 |    45 .. 62

Your error says

> has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class
> file **version 61.0**), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes
> class file versions **up to 52.0**

You have compiled with JAVA 17 and try to run it with JAVA 8. Switch either the compilation or the environment that runs the compiled application according to the above table.

Your **JRE 8  that exists in docker** supports **any code that is compiled with JDK 8 or earlier versions (1 .. 5, 6, 7)**  .

If you wish to compile the project with **JDK 17** you need to provide a **running environment in docker >= JDK 17**.

**Edit**:

Answering the comment

> I also wonder what is the image I should use to run the code that is
> compiled by JDK 17

try with

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine as my-app ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Frankly speaking, your answer is what I already know & mentioned in my post, my question is more about the detailed "how-to" solution, as you see from my post, I already tried to either compile code with older jdk but encounter error mentioned in my post, I also wonder what is the image I should use to run the code that is compiled by JDK 17.

Comment: @user842225 `Frankly speaking, your answer is what I already know & mentioned in my post` Also in your question `I would like to keep using that base image because it is small in size. So I decided to compile my code using java 11 jdk.` Please read my answer carefully and you will understand how to solve the issue. You need to built the project with `jdk8` or if you only can with `jdk11` then you have to provide to docker the `jdk11` as runntime

Comment: @user842225 `So, I wonder what is the proper way to have my project being built by java 11 jdk & I could still use that base image?` You CAN'T keep `JDK8` in docker as runntime environment and provide a class file compiled from `JDK11`

Comment: I believe I have read your answer carefully,  I fully understand what caused the problem, you answer has nicely explained that. but I am seeking for an answer that gives clear solution not only direction. Because I know the direction to solve it, either compile code with JDK8 or change base image runtime to JDK11+ , but what exactly the solution is what I am seeking here. Hope it clarifies. What I already tried  for a solution has mentioned in my post which ended up errors. For example, I am not sure which base image I should use.

Comment: @user842225 did you check my edited answer from yesterday. It should help with the solution you seek

Comment: Yes, I have checked your updated answer, if you read my OP carefully, you would see that I've tried it (though with version 11), conclusion is that simply changing the number from 8 to 11 or 17 doesn't help. The error is mentioned in my post, it looks like there is no such image.  If you have successfully built image with base image `openjdk:17-alpine` I would be interested to know.

Comment: @user842225 please check the docker website. According to this https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk?tab=tags&page=1&name=17-alpine my edited answer should work. The image for `jdk11` that you use does not exist. Here are https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk?tab=tags&page=1&name=11-jre-alpine all the available names. I doubt that it will work however with `JDK11` since you could not build the project with `JDK11` Best to try directly with `JDK17`

Comment: Thanks, I tried with the linked name, it works. I am not sure why it was failing with the same error when I copied the image name from your updated answer earlier, did you update the name multiple times in your answer?  Anyway, it works now.  I have a new issue now that running the jar would fail because the dependent library is missing in the jar...which I will create a new post.